# find -f results in unknown predicate in ubuntu, but works in macOS

Tags: bash, environment-variables, nodejs

I'm attempting to set an environment variable with the following script.
`find -f ./node_modules/@marcom/*/src/scss -type d -d 0 | tr $'\n' :`

This exact script works fine in macOS, however when I push to a remote server running ubuntu and attempt to run the same script, I get the result:

`find: unknown predicate '-f'`

I wasn't aware that find worked differently across OS variants, any pointers here would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have a working MacOS system, please check in `man find` what is the meaning of `-f` and tell us. Then we can tell you the corresponding expression in Linux. Otherwise you must wait for someone who knows `find` both in MacOS and Linux.

Comment: -f specifies the file hierarchy for find to traverse.

Comment: Thanks! Then you can simply remove it. The first parameter (if any) should be file hierarchy for find to traverse, so maybe `find /node_modules/@marcom/*/src/scss -type d -d 0 | tr $'\n' :` will do what you want. But I think you should also check the MacOS meaning of `-d` (I don't think it is the Linux '-depth`).